# JQuery concat selector with a object variable

Tags: jquery, selector

I've few `.children` element within a `.parent` div. I would like to loop the children elements.

```
//This is working good.
$('.parent .children').each(function(){
     //working good.
});

//But I would like to do that in the following way-
var parent = $('.parent');
$(parent + ' .children').each(function(){

});
```

This time I'm getting the following error-

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] .children

Any help?

Comment: `parent.find('.children').each()`?

Comment: or, `$('.children', parent)` pass parent element as context which us equivalent to ^^^^

Comment: Or you can use `$(parent.selector + ' .children').each(function(){});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method as follows:

```
parent.find('.children').each(function() { 
  // Loop here
});
```

Alternatively, pass `parent` as the [context](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) to the jQuery constructor as follows:

```
$('.children', parent).each(function() { 
  // Loop here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In above give problem.

```
//This is working good.
$('.parent .children').each(function(){
     //working good.
});
```

Above example your are finding children  class under parent class.

```
//But I would like to do that in the following way-
var parent = $('.parent');
$(parent + ' .children').each(function(){

});
```

In above example you are creating a object of parent class and that's why it is giving issue because wee need to pass string not a object .

Beloved example must help you.

```
var parent = $('.parent');
    parent.find('.children').each(function(){

    });
```

Here you are created a object and by use of find we are finding .children class inside a parent class.